# Embed sitemap in a page

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

I've seen that many sites have a dedicated page for a sitemap, not just an .xml file.

For example, https://www.casinos.de/sitemap/ They're using Yoast SEO and sitemap.xml is also available, but how can you embed the whole sitemap in a page like this?

Is there a function or just a `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` won’t work, as using that on an XML file will not create a list of links. WordPress has `wp_list_pages()` which will create a list of pages, but only pages, and that’s all. Whether Yoast has this feature is something you would need to ask its developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all the different post_types you have by using `get_post_types()`. Then you can loop through all posts of each post_types and echo all these posts (title + link). That way you have the freedom of formatting your sitemap the way you want.